# IDataRecord reader gets closed when calling Linq.First()

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datareader

For a piece of code like this which works fine -

```
foreach (var dataRecord in dataRecords)
{
    return dataRecord.GetDateTime("MaxLogDate");
}
```

I tried to replace it with

```
return dataRecords.First().GetDateTime("MaxLogDate");
```

but I got -

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to call MetaData when the reader is closed.'
```

Can you please guide me why and when is this reader getting closed?

Comment: How about converting `ToList()` before getting first? I imagine it's an interator type so iteration does something inside the object to open the reader

Comment: What is `dataRecords` and how do you get it?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that this always only returns data from the first record?

Comment: i only want first records data

Comment: converting toList throws same issue

Comment: calling .first() or .toList closes the IDataRecord

Comment: I am curious what is `datarecord`. Can you post the structure of `datarecord`. `GetDateTime()` is predefined or you have defined it?

Comment: its System.Data.IDataRecord.GetDateTime(int) inbuilt method, and SQLCommand.ExecuteReader() returns a collection of IDataRecord

Comment: @Muds remember to mark the answer

Comment: yea once i get the answer i will happily do it .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use it:

```
while(dataRecords.Read()){
    return dataRecords["columnName"].GetDateTime("MaxLogDate");
}
```

Comment: yea i get that, but question is i only need first to be returned so need for running it in a loop seems redundant

Comment: it doesn't loop anything if the return runs on the first data lol

Comment: if you look at my code, i have done exactly this but i want to understand why .first doesnt work

Comment: No, you didn't do my approach, you didn't read. Please try my answer ^^

Comment: bro, getting value isnt my aim here, i am trying to understand why your code works and other implementation doesnt, can you write a code without any loop ? that is my question

Comment: @MarcoSalerno The OP is confused by the `while`, and you make them more confused by saying the loop must be done. The loop (the `while`) must not be done, the `Read()` must. You can call `Read` once without a loop. You end up calling `Read()` once because you `return` from the loop, but if the intention is to call it once, then it's probably more readable to avoid having the loop.

Comment: So writing it out of the while will make any difference?

Comment: No, but it will convey your intention much clearer. `if (dataRecords.Read()) { return dataRecords["columnName"].GetDateTime("MaxLogDate"); }` is more understandable than `while(dataRecords.Read()) { return dataRecords["columnName"].GetDateTime("MaxLogDate"); }`.

Comment: Okay later i'm gonna edit the answer, i'm not on pc atm